# Decode sys calls?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly

How do you find out what number each sys call is? Like on SP3 ZwCreateFile is

```
ZwCreateFile:
    mov eax, 0x25
    mov edx, 0x7ffe0300
    call [edx]
    retn 0x2c
```

How do you find out that ZwCreateFile is 0x25?

Comment: it depends entirely on which OS you are running

Comment: Tag says windows :P. Would it differ between versions of windows?

Comment: It certainly *could* differ, which is a very good reason to just use the function they provide for you. Your desire to know the IDs suggests that you're about to do something you probably shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Things you aren't supposed to be doing are more fun though.

Comment: Poor logic! You are not supposed to open email attachments from strangers. Is that fun?

Comment: Hell ya! Love analyzing malware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows System Call Table (NT/2000/XP/2003/Vista)](http://www.metasploit.com/users/opcode/syscalls.html) says that `NtCreateFile` (the same function as `ZwCreateFile`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308302.aspx) and many others) is

```
      Windows NT          Windows 2000         Windows XP     W2K3    Vista
SP3  SP4  SP5  SP6  SP0  SP1  SP2  SP3  SP4  SP0  SP1  SP2  SP0  SP1  SP0
0x17 0x17 0x17 0x17 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x25 0x25 0x25 0x27 0x27 0x3b
```

You can easily discover these for yourself by dumping the syscall table `nt!KiServiceTable` using [kd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266319.aspx) or [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266321.aspx).

Information from the [Sysinternals forums](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=2705).

Answer (score 0):

Have your compiler generate a **map** file.  The **map** file contains function names and their locations (offsets, addresses or both).  Search the map file for an address and you should come up with a name for that address.

In your example, `ZwCreateFile` is not 0x25.  The processor dereferences the *{pointer}* value in `edx` and uses that value as the address for `ZwCreateFile`.  The address of `ZwCreateFile` cannot be obtained from the assembly language you posted.  The address of `ZwCreateFile` is stored in location 0x7ffe0300, which must have been initialized before this assembly language fragment.

Again, consult your **map** file.

Comment: I am not talking about the address. I am talking about ZwCreateFile's syscall id which is 0x25 on my version of windows.